# pub build throws errors in case of angular2 dart codegen

Tags: angular, dart, codegen

For a while I was under the impression that the Angular2 Dart codegen was the way forward with the development. Unfortunately it seems that as of late I can't use codegen anymore. Here is my pubspec.yaml which does not work and produces errors. By only removing the /transform/codegen part the error is gone.

```
name: frontend
version: 0.0.1
description: Regatta frontend
author:
homepage: https://regatta.atlassian.net
documentation:

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.19.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular2: 3.0.0-alpha
  angular2_components: 0.3.1-alpha
  reflectable: 1.0.1
  sass_transformer: 0.1.2+1
  greencat: 0.0.2
  browser: 0.10.0+2
  http: 0.11.3+9
  stream_transformers: 0.3.0+3

dev_dependencies:
  test: 0.12.19
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: 1.0.2
  dart_style: 0.2.16
  pageloader: 2.2.5
  mockito: 1.0.1
  angular_test: 1.0.0-alpha+5

transformers:
  - sass_transformer
  - angular2/transform/codegen:
      platform_directives:
        - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
      platform_pipes:
        - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
      entry_points: web/main.dart
      resolved_identifiers:
        BrowserClient: 'package:http/browser_client.dart'
        Client: 'package:http/http.dart'
  - angular2/transform/reflection_remover:
      $include:
        - test/**_test.dart
        - web/main.dart
  - reflectable:
      entry_points:
        - web/main.dart
      formatted: true
  - test/pub_serve:
      $include: test/**_test.dart
  - dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

Error message

```
pub build
Loading source assets... 
Loading angular2/transform/codegen, dart_to_js_script_rewriter, sass_transformer, reflectable, test/pub_serve and reflectable/src/transform_import transformers... 
Loading angular2 and angular2/transform/reflection_remover transformers... (3.9s)
[Error from DirectiveMetadataLinker on frontend|lib/components/navigation_bar_component/navigation_bar_component.ng_summary.json with input frontend|lib/components/navigation_bar_component/navigation_bar_component.ng_meta.json]:
Missing identifier "materialProviders" needed by "NavigationBarComponent" from metadata map
[Error from DirectiveMetadataLinker on frontend|lib/components/event_list_component/event_list_component.ng_summary.json with input frontend|lib/components/event_list_component/event_list_component.ng_meta.json]:
Missing identifier "materialProviders" needed by "EventListComponent" from metadata map
[Error from DirectiveMetadataLinker on frontend|lib/components/event_detail_component/event_detail_component.ng_summary.json with input frontend|lib/components/event_detail_component/event_detail_component.ng_meta.json]:
Missing identifier "materialProviders" needed by "EventDetailComponent" from metadata map
[Error from TemplateCompiler on frontend|lib/app_component.ng_meta.json]:
Could not find Directive/Pipe entry for name: NavigationBarComponent
. Please be aware that Dart transformers have limited support for reusable, pre-defined lists of Directives/Pipes (aka "directive/pipe aliases"). See  for details.
Building frontend... (12.2s)
```

Comment: Hi Fabian

I took a quick look - it does seem it does work - for example the gallery application (https://dart-lang.github.io/angular2_components_example/) is built using the same configuration and ahead-of-time code generation:

https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components_example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the standard transformer since it includes the reflection remover phase already https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2/blob/master/lib/src/transform/transformer.dart#L37.

If you must use the alternate transformer angular2/transform/codegen then you need a version of the angular2_components using the same transformer.

I experimented by adding this to your pubspec.yaml:

```
dependency_override
  angular2_components:
    path: ../../angular2_components
```

In the path I provided, I had a local clone of the git repo where I altered the pubspec.yaml file to use:

```
transformers:
  - angular2/transform/codegen:
  ...
```

That allowed the package to build.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to be the issue. I don't exactly know why I changed the transformer to codegen. I guess some tutorial must have suggested it and at that time it also worked. I now use the original transformer again and am happy with it. At least with this problem. The other one is in a separate bugreport...